# Populated Array Throws Undefined Offset: 1 In Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

I have a laravel 5.6 query that populates an array with a single result to pass to a view.
This is the query :

```
 $farms=DB::select("select pic,shop_name,StateName,amount,
 duration,ror,farm_shop.id from farm_shop join states on states.id=farm_shop.state_id where 
  farm_shop.id=:id",['id' => $id]);
```

A `print_r` command returns this:

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [pic] => 
 092720180421565bac5ae4974f9MAIN.jpg 
 [shop_name] => Pig Farm [StateName] => STATEGTR 
 [amount] => 3000000 [duration] => 11 [ror] => 28 [id] => 4 ) )
```

My view accesses it like this :

```
  @foreach($farms->as $farmshop)
<div class="row course-set courses__row col-md-6 col-offset-md-3">
 @php
$pic="http://xxxxxx/storage/".$farmshop['pic'];
@endphp
<section class="col-md-3">
         <img src="{{$pic}}" alt="" width="1200" height="1200" title="xxx">
         <div class="text-center"><b>{{$farmshop['shop_name']}}</b><br/>
          Location: {{$farmshop[['StateName']}}
          <br/>
           Amount (X):<span style="color:red">
   <b> {{number_format($farmshop['amount'],2)}}</b></span><br/>
      Period (Months):&nbsp;{{$farmshop['duration']}}<br/>
     Rate (%): {{$farmshop['ror']}} <div class="text- 
    center">
     <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
 <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Invest</a>
</div>

              <div>&nbsp;</div>
          </div>


        </section>

</div>
 @endforeach
```

The error that now gets thrown is :

> Undefined offset: 1

And the below line gets highlighted in the inbuilt laravel function compileForEach($expression):

> ```
>  $iteratee = trim($matches[1]);
> ```

Please how do i resolve this?..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in this line of code: `@foreach($farms->as $farmshop)`

Correct code is supposed to be : `@foreach($farms as $farmshop)`

Thanks